# Почему не отправляет на gmail? python(django)

Tags: python, html, django

Вроде все правильно, но выводит ошибку:

```
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w17sm9933602ljd.2 - gsmtp')
```

Файл views.py :

```
def remember(request):
global isauth
global all_objects_accounts
global nameforid
if request.method == "POST":
    for i in all_objects_accounts:
        if i.login == request.POST['login'] and i.email == request.POST['email'] and i.date == request.POST['date']:
            print(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER + "" + settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
            send_mail('aaa', 'aaa', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['sopotim373@yunchali.com'], fail_silently=False)  
return render(request, 'main/remember.html', {'isauth': isauth, 'all_objects_accounts': all_objects_accounts, 'nameforid': nameforid})
```

Файл settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

Comment: А все очевидные вещи на странице https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials уже проверены? И, помоему, без SSL уже работать не будет, это последняя строчка в приведенном конфиге

Comment: Все проверено и c SSL =True тоже пробовал

Comment: А можно туда в файл дописать какой нибудь вывод на консоль, чтобы, прежде чем слать письмо, на консоль вывелись имя пользователя и пароль? Есть подозрение, что ругань "Username and Password not accepted" неспроста...

Comment: Все выводиться правильно

Comment: Гугл может фильтровать Ваш IP при попытке отослать по SMTP, но тогда, мне кажется, ошибка бы была другая. Решением было бы написать простой скрипт, который БЕЗ ДЖАНГО отправляет из питончика письмо. Если скриптзаработает - значит надо копатьяс в джанге, не заработает - думать, Как обмануть гугл